# populating a mysql table with json objects using forloops

Tags: java, mysql, json, loops

i have a json object which i have manipulated and assigned to normal java global variables.

i iterated through the objects and printed them and it worked. 
i encapusulated the global variable to enable me create an instance in another class and use a get method to access them and populate my mysql table with them.

```
JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(finaljson);
for (int i = 0; parentArray.length() > i; i++) {
    JSONObject objj = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
    country = objj.getString("country_name");
    leaguename = objj.getString("league_name");
    System.out.println(country + "   " + leaguename);
}
```

But it is returning null and i don't know how to fix it.
i expected it to return strings for me.

Comment: What is null exactly?

Comment: When I print it to console it shows null.  Probably meaning it is returning empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check the [json data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) in MySQL which lets you store data as a JSON object and you can access it using key using JSON_EXTRACT.

Comment: okay, @GEE please mark the solution so that others can figure out the status.